# Move Exchange mail item and hide the output of the move?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I have the following powershell code to check the inbox for any messages and move them to the relevant sub folders under inbox (creating the folder if it does not exist)

```
function CreateFolder($MailboxName) 
{
"Mailbox Name : " + $MailboxName
"Folder Name : " + $newFolderName
$folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$ibInboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchangeservice,$folderid)
$fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)
$SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$newFolderName)
$findFolderResults = $exchangeService.FindFolders($ibInboxFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView)
    if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -eq 0) 
    {
        "Doesn't Exist"
        $NewFolder = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder($exchangeService)
        $NewFolder.DisplayName = $newFolderName
        $NewFolder.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
        "Folder Created"
        $mailItem.Move($findFolderResults.id)
    }
    else 
    {
        "Folder Already Exist"
        $mailItem.Move($findFolderResults.id)
    }

}

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web 
Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

#$creds = Get-Credential

$global:exchangeService = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1) 
$exchangeService.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials -ArgumentList $creds.UserName, $creds.GetNetworkCredential().password 
$exchangeService.Url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchangeService,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(10)
$mailItems = $inbox.FindItems($view)

foreach($mailItem in $mailItems)
{       
    $newFolderName = $mailItem.From.Name #$mailItem.Sender.Name
    CreateFolder($creds.UserName)
}
```

However when it runs I get the following output per mail item:

```
Mailbox Name : bob.gently@bob.com
Folder Name : Gently, Bob
Folder Already Exist
ToRecipients                 : {}
BccRecipients                : {}
CcRecipients                 : {}
ConversationTopic            : 
ConversationIndex            : 
From                         : 
IsAssociated                 : 
IsDeliveryReceiptRequested   : 
IsRead                       : 
[ ... ]
```

How can I hide the `$mailItem.Move` output? Is it something to do with the `$findFolderResults.id` being an array?

Comment: you could pipe it to `out-null` like `$mailItem.Move($findFolderResults.id) | Out-Null`

Comment: lol, always something simple, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

as per gpunktschmitz's comment just need to append | out-null to hide the output